# Correct path to publish to IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I've managed to deploy my website to test through Publish Web in VS2012 using the connection criteria below. This launches fine and works as expected but I need to keep clicking the publish button each time to get the page to launch.

[image]

However, rather than keep publishing each time, I'm trying to run it directly from IIS by opening IIS (inetmgr) select the site folder and browse. However, it tries to launch `localhost/MyWebsite/` and not the full path `localhost/MyWebsite/home.aspx` so I get a blank page.

The project also has the home.aspx set as start page. Can anyone point out why I can't get this to run from IIS where it's already published? It's probably something obvious but I can't see it.

[image]

Comment: try with defaul.aspx instead of home.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ON IIS, go to DEFAULT and add HOME.aspx, on the top of the list.

Comment: Excellent. So simple when you know what you're doing! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, you specifying that you want to browse that site which is "localhost/MyWebSite/"  you could go into "Content View" and select "Home.aspx" and then select browse if you want the full path to that file for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Insted of setting default document from IIS set it from web.config . so that you no need to set default document every time .

Web.config

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <defaultDocument enabled="true">
     <files>
        <add value="home.html" />
     </files>
  </defaultDocument>
```